# Start emacs 23.1 on windows XP only once (emacsclientw.exe)

Tags: windows-xp, emacs, emacsclient

I have `(server-start)` in my .emacs file and set the variables HOME, ALTERNATE_EDITOR (=runemacs.exe) and EMACS_SERVER_FILE set.

When I start

```
emacsclientw.exe  test.txt
```

the first time, I expect emacs to start and display the buffer `test.txt`
What happens is that emacs is started and the buffer *scratch* is displayed, the messsage line says (New file) and the buffer test.txt exists, but is not yet displayed.
(That's not really what is bothering me right now)

When I now execute

> emacsclientw.exe  test2.txt

I expect that the same emacs is used and a new buffer `test2.txt`is created.

But what happens is that a new emacs is started with an open warning buffer reading:

```
Warning (server): Unable to start the Emacs server.
There is an existing Emacs server, named "server".
To start the server in this Emacs process, stop the existing
server or call `M-x server-force-delete' to forcibly disconnect it.
```

This sounds to me as if the first instance starts a server, but the second does not connect to it but instead tries to start server again.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Currently, I used the following solution.

Add to your .emacs file:

```
(load "server")
(unless (server-running-p) (server-start))
```

The solution comes from [How to start emacs server only if it is not started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570451/how-to-start-emacs-server-only-if-it-is-not-started)

Answer (score 0):

You should start Emacs using

```
runemacs.exe
```

After that you can use

```
emacsclientw.exe  test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but -- Nope, it has the same effect. And if it would work, it would not be what I need, since I will have to start emacs always in the same way..

Answer (score 0):

If you alread have `(server-start)` in your .emacs file, you might want to check The Emacs Wiki.  It has some good information about using [emacsclient under MS Windows](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient#toc4).

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, your emacs server is creating its server file in a place where `emacsclientw` cannot find. To debug the issue further, you can run emacs, and see that the server file specified in `EMACS_SERVER_FILE` is indeed created.

In my setup, the only environment variable I use is `HOME`. The custom variable `server-name` is left at its default value (i.e. `server`). This causes the file `$HOME/.emacs.d/server/server` to be created when I run emacs. And since this location is the default, `emacsclientw.exe` is able to locate this file, and determine how to talk to emacs.

I had a quick look at `server.el` in my system, and I couldn't see anything about `EMACS_SERVER_FILE` in it. If you use a non-standard location, that might be the cause of your problems.